# duplicate values in array when adding dynamic post data

Tags: php

I have the following post data which increments based on the number of inputs resulting in a dynamic post name.

```
Array ( [VAL0] => TESTING [UNIT0] => 99 [VAL1] => TESTING1 [UNITS1] => 88 )
```

I'm completing a loop on the post data to find the `VAL` and `UNIT` posts and assign them to an variable and then array.

its working except for 1 set of values are being duplicated.

can anyone see where i am going wrong?

```
$bulkProducts = array();
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        if (strpos($key, "VAL")===0) {

            $val= $value;

        }
        if (strpos($key, "UNIT")===0) {

            $newunits= $value;
        }
        if (isset($val,$newunits)) {
            $products = array();
            $products = array('VAL' => $val,
                        'UNITS' =>$newunits
                             );
            array_push($bulkProducts,$products);            
        }               
    }   
    print_r($bulkProducts);
```

print r result :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [VAL] => TESTING [UNITS] => 99 ) [1] => Array ( [VAL] => TESTING1 [UNITS] => 88 ) [2] => Array ( [VAL] => TESTING1 [UNITS] => 88 ) )
```

Comment: Why are you using `strrpos`?

Comment: that should be strpos - used to check if the VAL post exists as its could be VAL0, VAL1,VAL2 etc..

Comment: Next question, what is `$sku`? Is it set further up?

Comment: sorry @JonStirling that should be $val - updated now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change here:

```
   if (isset($val,$newunits)) {
        $products = array('VAL' => $val,
                    'UNITS' =>$newunits
                         ); 
        $val = NULL; $newunits = NULL;
        array_push($bulkProducts,$products);            
    }
```

Comment: at the beginning $val = null, $newunits = null. on first turn $val = $value, $newunits = null, on second both $value and added, on third $val = $value again and $newunits already set from the last turn. so added again before 4th execution. so u have to set them both null after added to array on 2nd turn